# Cookie и laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Пытаюсь установить куку в laravel 5 стандартным методом, т.е.

```
Cookie::make('room_1', $data, $minutes);
```

Но к сожалению это не выходит, пробывал добавить в очередь средство queue

```
Cookie::queue('room_1', $data, $minutes);
```

Это заработало, но все же хочется узнать, почему же не работает make, запускаю в контроллере при загрузки страницы

Answer (score 1):

Make только устанавливает куку, а еще еще надо передать клиенту, например:

```
$cookie = Cookie::make('room_1', $data, $minutes);
return $response()->withCookie(cookie($cookie));
```

То же самое можно сделать так:

```
$cookie = Cookie::queue('room_1', $data, $minutes);
return $response();
```